# Saving Google Doc as PDF through Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been stumped on this problem for a while now, and since I'm not that familiar with coding, I come you you for help. For this project, I am filing in a template from information off a google form. Here's the process:
1. Fill out google form which saves data in a google sheet
2. google sheet runs the script once a form is submitted
3. the script opens and edits the google doc and saves it as a google doc in a folder

So far that all works, the google doc is edited exactly how I want it. What I cannot figure out is how to end the process by saving that doc as a PDF without having to do it manually. If the script can copy and edit a doc, then surely it can be saved as a PDF. Here is my code and any guidance would be very helpful, thanks!

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var InvenName = e.values[1];
  var Case = e.values[2];
  var AppNumber = e.values[3];
  var Firm = e.values[4];
  var InvenTitle = e.values[5];
  var Date = e.values[6];
  var AppType = e.values[7];

  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('FILE ID HERE'); 

  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID HERE')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(Case + ' ' + 'E Assigmnt' + ' ' + AppType + ' ' + AppNumber + ' ' + InvenName ,folder);

  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 

  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  var footer = doc.getFooter();

  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{Name}}', InvenName);
  body.replaceText('{{Title}}' ,InvenTitle);
  body.replaceText('{{AppNumber}}', AppNumber);
  body.replaceText('{{Date}}' , Date);
  footer.replaceText('{{Firm}}', LFirm);
  footer.replaceText('{{Case}}', Case);

  //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes

  doc.saveAndClose();
  var docblob = doc.getBlob();
  docblob.getAs('application/pdf').setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
  DriveApp.createFile(docblob);

}
```

Comment: So as it turns out this is actually working, but the PDFs are saving on my main drive. how do I save them to a specific folder?

Comment: Find a folder id that you wish to use and `const folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('id'); folder.createFile(docblob);`

Comment: If your question is how to save a file in a specific folder. This will help you: [Specify folder to save files to in Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501461/specify-folder-to-save-files-to-in-google-script)